# Is there a way to create a dataframe from a Dictionary inside a list?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe named layout where it has a column named layout(yes same name) with nested data like this.

```
[{'floors': [{'floor_id': 1024,
        'floor_name': 'Apartment',
        'rooms': [{'devices': [1017,
           1021,
           1032,
           1038,
           1041,
           1048,
           1052,
           1060,
           1016,
           1062,
           1069,
           1048],
          'room_id': 1025,
          'room_name': 'Living room'},
         {'devices': [1018,
           1022,
           1037,
           1047,
           1067,
           1070,
           1073,
           1079,
           1080,
           1081,
           1041,
           1045,
           1047],
          'room_id': 1026,
          'room_name': 'Kitchen'},
         {'devices': [1034,
           1036,
           1046,
           1050,
           1049,
           1055,
           1071,
           1074,
           1076,
           1044,
           1046],
          'room_id': 1027,
          'room_name': 'Bathroom'},
         {'devices': [1023, 1033, 1045, 1054, 1075, 1042],
          'room_id': 1028,
          'room_name': 'Bedroom 1'},
         {'devices': [1020, 1051, 1053, 1066, 1068, 1077, 1078, 1043],
          'room_id': 1029,
          'room_name': 'Bedroom 2'}]},
       {'floor_id': 1021,
        'floor_name': 'First',
        'rooms': [{'room_id': 1023, 'room_name': 'Kitchen', 'devices': [1019]},
         {'room_id': 1024, 'room_name': 'Beedroom', 'devices': [1030]},
         {'room_id': 1025, 'room_name': 'Store', 'devices': [1035]}]},
       {'floor_id': 1026,
        'floor_name': 'Ground',
        'rooms': [{'room_id': 1027, 'room_name': 'Hall', 'devices': [1032, 1033]},
         {'room_id': 1028, 'room_name': 'Gallery', 'devices': [1022, 1034]}]}]}]
```

Is there a way to put this in a single dataframe? I want something like floor_id and floor_name value should be common for all rows. The problem i'm getting is dealing with the key 'rooms'. I want the dataframe to directly have a column named devices( which is inside rooms ) and contain numbers in devices as rows. Then the last columns will be room_id and room_name

| floor_id | floor_name | devices | room_id | room_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1024 | Apartment | 1017 | 1025 | Living room |
| 1024 | Apartment | 1021 | 1025 | Living room |
| 1024 | Apartment | 1032 | 1025 | Living room |
| ....... |  |  |  |  |
| 1024 | Apartment | 1068 | 1029 | Bedroom 2 |
| 1024 | Apartment | 1077 | 1029 | Bedroom 2 |
| 1024 | Apartment | 1078 | 1029 | Bedroom 2 |
| 1024 | Apartment | 1043 | 1029 | Bedroom 2 |

i tried using

```
    pd.DataFrame(layout.iloc[0]['layout'])
```

but i get

floors
0   [{'floor_id': 1024, 'floor_name': 'Apartment',...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should *explode* the nested dictionary into a flat one with a comprehension:

```
data = layout.iloc[0]['layout']
df = pd.DataFrame([{'floor_id': floor['floor_id'], 'floor_name': floor['floor_name'],
       'devices': device, 'room_id': room['room_id'],
       'room_name': room['room_name']} for floor in data[0]['floors']
      for room in floor['rooms'] for device in room['devices']])
```

It gives as expected:

```
    floor_id floor_name  devices  room_id    room_name
0       1024  Apartment     1017     1025  Living room
1       1024  Apartment     1021     1025  Living room
2       1024  Apartment     1032     1025  Living room
3       1024  Apartment     1038     1025  Living room
4       1024  Apartment     1041     1025  Living room
5       1024  Apartment     1048     1025  Living room
6       1024  Apartment     1052     1025  Living room
7       1024  Apartment     1060     1025  Living room
8       1024  Apartment     1016     1025  Living room
9       1024  Apartment     1062     1025  Living room
10      1024  Apartment     1069     1025  Living room
11      1024  Apartment     1048     1025  Living room
12      1024  Apartment     1018     1026      Kitchen
13      1024  Apartment     1022     1026      Kitchen
...
```